# Are there German words that get pronounced differently based on whether they are capitalized?

Tags: pronunciation, capitalization

Are there words in the German language where `abcde` and `Abcde` are both valid words but they get pronounced slightly differently? Maybe words that are stressed differently? Is there any case where the capitalion has an effect on the pronunciation?

Comment: Do you want a complete list or does one example like _Weg_ ‘way’ (long vowel) and _weg_ ‘away’ (short vowel) suffice? Most other cases are construed, though.

Comment: @Crissov: I think the question is quite clear on that, it’s a yes/no question.

Comment: @chirlu True, but that way it’s not challenging (or interesting) at all, since this even happens in English, e.g. _China_ vs. _china_ ‘Porzellan’.

Comment: @Crissov: You can ask a separate question about listing all cases, then. :-) Many questions here aren’t particularly challenging _for us_.

Comment: It's an interesting questions for the purpose of the Anki extension AwesomeTTS : https://github.com/AwesomeTTS/AwesomeTTS/issues/95

Comment: @Crissov, I do not think that the pronunciation of “china” differs from that of “China”.

Comment: @CarstenS Right. I don’t know why I added that part. It would only be relevant for the simpler question whether there are words that only differ by capitalization.

Comment: @Crissov, ah, I see.

Comment: I mentioned another possibly relevant corner case on the GitHub issue.

Comment: @Crissov: For what it's worth, not all that much in a question about German, a commonly-used example for English is Polish (adjective, native to Poland) vs polish (verb, to make shiny).

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that for example *weg* and *Weg* are **two different words**, and not one word with different capitalization as someone coming from a case insensitive language could possibly assume (the question hints to that). The fact that the two words use the same letters is irrelevant here.

Comment: Hauptwörter und Nichthauptwörter erfüllen in Sätzen unterschiedliche Funktionen, und daher kann man in einem Satz nicht einfach ein Hauptwort durch ein Verb, beispielsweise, ersetzen. Es ändern sich Wortstellung und Bedeutung und damit die Betonung.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there are: *Weg* [veːk], *weg* [vɛk]. It is, however, not the capitalization itself that affects pronunciation; it just so happens that one of the words is a noun and therefore capitalized.

Comment: As you said yourself it is not the capitalization that affects the pronunciation.  But that exactly was the question. Do you know any example where the same word is pronunced differently because of the capitalization?

Comment: @Awita I assume there’s a good example of a one-word initialism vs. a letter-by-letter acronym vs. an expanded abbreviation vs. a normal word. Alas, I can’t think of any right now. _ARM, Arm, arm_ are all pronounced the same, for instance. The definition of “word” also matter, e.g. lexicon entry vs. part of a sentence.

Comment: @Awita : It depends on the definition of word. For this question I purposefully spoke about what I mean by asking whether `abcde` and `Abcde` get pronounced differently. It's what I want to know.

Comment: @christian: the problem is, that every word gets capitalised at the beginning of a sentence - do you include those?

Comment: @Gerhard : I care about words as they are written in the Duden.

Comment: Since capitalisation means it's a noun and non-capitalisation means it's not, they can't ever be the same word, just related words.

Answer (score 6):

Except from the example "Weg" there is no common such pair.

However, capitalising things works as an emphasizer, and that *does* affect pronunciation somewhat; it might be slower, more majestic, etc.

Douglas Adams, *Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency*:

> The door was the way to... to... The Door was The Way. Good. Capital
>   letters were always the best way of dealing with things you didn't
>   have a good answer to.

This effect works just the same way in German:

> Die Tür war Der Weg.

This would certainly affect the pronunciation of the articles, when compared to their normal pronunciation.

Comment: The word »der« is an article, not a noun. So writing it as »Der« when it is not the first word of a sentence, is wrong. If you want to emphasize it, you can write it completely in uppercase (»DER«) or bold (»**der**«) in italics (»*der*«), underlines (sorry, can't show this here) or spaced (»d e r«). But first letter uppercase and all other lowercase (»Der«) when not being the first word of a sentence is definitely wrong in German.

Answer (score 1):

If there are words that differ solely by capitalisation and pronunciation, they are very few. Apart from *Weg* and *weg* I cannot think of any.

In fact, homographes that aren’t homophones (so words that are written the same but not pronounced the same) are extremely rare in German. Short vowels are typically marked by a double consonant (and/or a consonant cluster) following. Long vowels are either unmarked, marked by doubling or by *h* (or *e*). Only for a set of very short words (often with grammatical function, according to the official rules) can the vowel be short and the final consonant undoubled.

Only if one of those short words which has a short vowel but no double consonant accidentally is written the same way as a different word that has a long vowel **and** if one of the two words is a noun will they accidentally have different pronunciation but differ only in capitalisation (since nouns are always capitalised).

Stress is *not* affected by capitalisation and shifted stress is usually also indicated by shifted length marking. So the *Weg/weg* case is very special.

Comment: One other case where vowel length is ambiguous is before _ch_ and _sch_, because those can’t be doubled. This leads to pairs such as _Sucht_ [zʊχt] vs. _sucht_ [zuːχt] (a form of the verb _suchen_), and _Hochzeit_ ‘wedding’ [​ˈ​hɔχ-] vs. _Hochzeit_ ‘flourish’ [​ˈ​hoːχ-]. (The realization of the /x/ may differ, too; personally, I tend to use [x] after a long _o_ or _u_ and [χ] after short _o_ or _u_ and any _a_.)

Comment: Of course, _Sucht_ is not another valid example for this particular question, because the OP was looking for dictionary lemmas, not inflected forms; and _Hochzeit_ even less, obviously.

Comment: @chirlu Good point! This also brings up the pre-reformed spelling with examples such as *Floß* and *floß* — the latter is now *floss* to show the short vowel pronunciation. *Hochzeit* is, of course, even more interesting because it requires a capital in any case.

Comment: Another example of the _Hochzeit_ type is _Lache_ (‘small pool’ vs. ‘manner of laughing’). There are also names, such as _Gesche_ and _Tuchel_, but names are special anyway, of course.

Answer (score 0):

No, capitalization never has effect on pronunciation in german language.

Comment: It has, however, tremendous effect on spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, here is another homophone which is a lower-case-homograph only:

> lüstern vs. Lüstern

lüstern = lewd [adjective]

Lüstern = lustres/chandeliers [dative form of noun]

There is no difference in pronunciation, although both have different roots.